# is it possible in symfony to propagate a variable from one table to another and that same variable to another table?

Tags: php, symfony, join, entity, var

From service to the user table:

```
 /**
     * @var \Servicio
     *
     * 
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Servicio", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Servicio_idServicio", referencedColumnName="idServicio")
     * })
     */
    private $servicioIdservicio;
```

From the user table to another one:

```
/**
     * @var \Usuario
     *
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Usuario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idUsuario", referencedColumnName="idUsuario")
     * })
     */
    private $Idusuario;

    /**
     * @var \Usuario
     *
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Usuario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Usuario_Servicio_idServicio", referencedColumnName="Servicio_idServicio")
     * })
     */
    private $usuarioServicioIdservicio;
```

when I want to create an object I am asked for two user objects when the second one comes from service but when I travel from user it comes out as a user object.

How can I solve this?

When I create an Incidence object that drags the user it asks me to add a user object for $iduser and another user object for $userServiceIdservice, because I get from the user table the $idservice. what it should ask me are integers not objects no? I don't know if the migration has been done wrong or what I should do to create an object incidence.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more and clear what you want to achieved please!

Comment: is something better understood?